# Python comma for loop conditional comma seperation

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want, when i for loop, there will be comma in the end of each item except the last item, last item should be dot

```
x = ['df', 'second', 'something', 'another']

separator = ''
for i in x:

  r = i
  print(r, separator)
  separator = ','
else:
  separator = '.'
```

this is my current code.

My expected result should be like this below:

```
df,
second ,
something ,
another.
```

can anyone help me in this case?

Comment: Why not `,` after `df`? Can you explain detail rules?

Comment: should in df too, sorry

Comment: Would you check all answers and choose one of them to resolve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `enumerate`

**Ex:**

```
x = ['df', 'second', 'something', 'another']
l = len(x)-1
for i, v in enumerate(x):
    if i != l:
        print(v, ",")
    else:
        print(v.strip()+".")
```

**Output:**

```
df ,
second ,
something ,
another.
```

---

or if you want it in a single line comma seperated use

```
print(", ".join(x) + ".") # -->df, second, something, another.
```

Answer (score 0):

use **end** in print.

```
x = ['df', 'second', 'something', 'another']

separator = ''
for i in x:

    r = i
    if r != x[-1]:
        print(r, end=',\n')
    else:
        print(r, end='.')
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some options for you.

#### Output:

```
df,
second,
something,
another.
```

#### Simplest version:

```py
x = ['df', 'second', 'something', 'another']

print(*x, sep=',\n', end='.')
```

#### Using `str.join`

```py
print(',\n'.join(x) + '.')
```

---

#### Using slicing

```py
for i in x[:-1]:
    print(f'{i},')
print(f'{x[-1]}.')
```

---

#### Using unpacking

```py
*rest, last = x
for i in rest:
    print(f'{i},')
print(f'{last}.')
```